# Texlive on FreeBSD - status

Tags: texlive

I heard about issues with porting texlive to FreeBSD and that there were two competing ports, of which one has been released but rejected, while another is being anticipated but not released... But no idea of when this situcation may resolve itself with a release. Does anyone know the status/timeline for porting texlive to FreeBSD?

Comment: The [TUG TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive) has precompiled binaries for i386-freebsd and amd64-freebsd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeXLive is now usable on FreeBSD. There is a [texlive-base](http://www.freshports.org/print/texlive-base/) and [texlive-texmf](http://www.freshports.org/print/texlive-texmf/) port. If you don't want install from port you can install from packages.

So: it's 100% ready-to-use (I'm using almost one year without any problem).

Comment: What is the difference between the two ports you have mentioned?

Comment: The texlive-base is the binaries, the texlive-texmf is the sty files, fonts, etc. (the "texmf-tree").

Comment: That would be outdated texlive 2012. I was hoping for the latest 2013.

Comment: I think in (basic) daily use there is no difference in texlive-bin 2012 and 2013. But the texlive-texmf... so I want version 2013, I've send a patch: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=ports/181675 . I'm using texlive-texmf-2013 (with texlive-bin-2012) and works well.

Comment: @ajeh good news: texlive-2014 is available in ports tree! You can build and install it - and maybe from packages in some days.